# BroadCast Receiver java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am making an android application for a capture bar code.Basically what the application is: from a Navigation Drawer I select an Item that brings me to a fragment and in this fragment there are a spinner and two text view, I select a product of the spinner, after I put the kilos manually and with the capture reader the bar code and when it reads the code sends the data to the database, but when I am going to another Item in the menu and perform the same procedure when it reads the barcode the system crashes and does not rescue any value. I've been like two weeks trying to solve this problem and I do not know why this happens Pleased Help!

```
private BroadcastReceiver mSamDataReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    kilos = edt1.getText().toString().trim();
    if (intent.getAction().equals(SCN_CUST_ACTION_SCODE)) {
        codigo_barras = intent.getStringExtra(SCN_CUST_EX_SCODE);
        edt2.setText(codigo_barras);

        System.out.println(kilos+ " " + codigo_barras+" "+ nombre);

        if (edt2 !=null){

            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),R.string.msjeEnvio,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }){

                @Override
                protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put(CATEGORIA,nombre);
                    params.put(CODIGO,codigo_barras);
                    params.put(KILOS,kilos);
                    return params;
                }

                };

                                Req.getInstance(getActivity()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
```

> 10-26 01:52:48.961 5742-5742/cl.parmex.lfigueroa.inventario
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                     at android.widget.Toast.(Toast.java:92)
>                                                                                     at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:238)
>                                                                                     at
>   cl.parmex.lfigueroa.inventario.SpinFragment$2$2.onErrorResponse(SpinFragment.java:244)
>                                                                                     at com.android.volley.Request.deliverError(Request.java:598)
>                                                                                     at
>   com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:101)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5136)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>                                                                                     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>                                                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Can we please get the `Logcat` / `Crash log` dump? thanks you

Comment: Where exactly are you getting the NPE? Will you please provide the error trace? I would like to help, but it's not clear yet where your error is.

Comment: your getActivity() might be returning null

Comment: @SravanKumar I think the error is because when I go to another Item in the menu and I do the same procedure the variable is empty and I don't know why

Comment: @NouvelTravay I already put the error down the code

Comment: @andre3wap I already put the error down the code

Comment: Network operation may take a while to execute. In the mean time you are moving to another fragment, this action will detach the previous fragment from the activity if you are using replace during fragment transaction. In this case getActivity will return null.

check whether fragment is added to activity using isAdded() funtion before showing toast

Comment: @Leslie Karen Figueroa Meneses -I edited the question and made the error more legible

Comment: @SravanKumar I only have just one fragment I just change the contents of the spinner but I only use the same fragment

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting a NullPointerException is because the context is null by the time the callback returns. This is one of the major issues with using Volley. You have to structure your program in such a way that the context is still valid. I will really leave that part up to you, but perhaps you want to use the Application level Context as opposed to the Activity level Context.

Note: In case it's not clear, when you use `getActivity()` you are actually using the Activity-level Context.

Comment: How Should I do that? I though I already did that when I created the class Req. And declared In the Android Manifest

Comment: In `Toast.makeText(getActivity(),error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` instead of using getActivity(), you should try getApplicationContext().